# Does Firebase's onSnapshot() re-render in react native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I was using a way to get data from the firestore database and then updated a useState variable in another component to re-render the screen with the new data whenever a change was made.

```
// from component 1
const [List, setList] = useState([])
```

```
// from component 2
// this gets all of the documents from a collection and stores them in a list, 
// then updates 'setList' with the retrieved data
const tempList = []
       const getData = await dataQuery.then( (val) => {
           val.forEach(doc => {
               //console.log(doc.id, "=> ", doc.data())
               tempList.push([doc.id, doc.data()])
           }, (err => {
               console.log(err)
           }))
       })
       prop.setList(tempList)
```

but I changed all of that and used onSnapshot() for realtime updates and It seems like I don't need to update setList for a re-render at all.

```
// from component 2
const getData = onSnapshot(doc(FIRESTORE_DB, "CollectionData", "CollectionDoc"), (doc) => {})
```

this seems like it causes a re-render with the proper updates, but I'm not sure why. Since I'm not changing 'setList', I have no idea what it's doing. is it re-rendering every component that has that collection open? for now it seems to do what I intended it to do, but it may not in the future so I would like to understand it a bit better.

I'd rather not leave this code in the "not sure how it works, but glad it does" bin. I'd like to understand it so I can avoid future problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In react, whenever a state changes,it triggers a re-render. So by using onSnapshot, you are effectively subscribing to real-time changes in the Firestore collection. When changes occur, the callback function inside onSnapshot is executed, but importantly, you are not manually updating the state with setList. Instead, the real power of onSnapshot is that it **automatically triggers a re-render of your component** **with the updated data** **every time** a change occurs in the Firestore collection.

This is why you're getting the desired behavior without explicitly calling setList when using onSnapshot. The component automatically re-renders whenever there are changes in the Firestore collection, keeping the UI up to date with the latest data.

Comment: Ah that's nice to know. However, in this case there are 2 components: 1st component has the setList. The 2nd component has the onSnapshot call. So howcome the 1st component is being re-rendered when the onSnapshot is called in the 2nd component? Edit: It's probably because the 2nd component is a child of the 1st component. Correct me if I'm mistaken.